# In modifying .smali files, Injecting some code crash at particular code point

Tags: android, crash, code-injection, smali

I have a question.
I'm trying to inject some code into particular code point.
At almost point, Code injection were successful.

But a code injection was failed at *'a'* method in *'com/google/ads/e'* package.
The code point is between *':goto_2'* and *'return v0'*.

At the point, some code like *'const/4 v1, 0x1'* are OK
but, other code like *'const-string v1, "aaa"', 'new-instance v1, ~', 'sget v1, ~'* crash when app are running, although v1 don't effect remain code.

This problem seem to correlate monitor instruction. But i don't know why this problem happen.

```
.method private a(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/app/Activity;Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest;Lcom/google/ads/f;Ljava/util/HashMap;J)Z
.locals 7

new-instance v0, Lcom/google/ads/h;

iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/ads/e;->a:Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;

invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;->h()Lcom/google/ads/m;

move-result-object v1

iget-object v1, v1, Lcom/google/ads/m;->k:Lcom/google/ads/util/i$b;

invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/google/ads/util/i$b;->a()Ljava/lang/Object;

move-result-object v2

check-cast v2, Lcom/google/ads/internal/h;

move-object v1, p0

move-object v3, p4

move-object v4, p1

move-object v5, p3

move-object v6, p5

invoke-direct/range {v0 .. v6}, Lcom/google/ads/h;-><init>(Lcom/google/ads/e;Lcom/google/ads/internal/h;Lcom/google/ads/f;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest;Ljava/util/HashMap;)V

monitor-enter v0

:try_start_0
invoke-virtual {v0, p2}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->a(Landroid/app/Activity;)V
:try_end_0
.catchall {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catchall_0

:goto_0
:try_start_1
invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->c()Z

move-result v1

if-nez v1, :cond_0

const-wide/16 v1, 0x0

cmp-long v1, p6, v1

if-lez v1, :cond_0

invoke-static {}, Landroid/os/SystemClock;->elapsedRealtime()J

move-result-wide v1

invoke-virtual {v0, p6, p7}, Ljava/lang/Object;->wait(J)V

invoke-static {}, Landroid/os/SystemClock;->elapsedRealtime()J
:try_end_1
.catch Ljava/lang/InterruptedException; {:try_start_1 .. :try_end_1} :catch_0
.catchall {:try_start_1 .. :try_end_1} :catchall_0

move-result-wide v3

sub-long v1, v3, v1

sub-long/2addr p6, v1

goto :goto_0

:catch_0
move-exception v1

:try_start_2
new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

const-string v2, "Interrupted while waiting for ad network to load ad using adapter class: "

invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-virtual {v1, p1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1

invoke-static {v1}, Lcom/google/ads/util/b;->a(Ljava/lang/String;)V

:cond_0
iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/ads/e;->a:Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;

invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;->m()Lcom/google/ads/internal/g;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->e()Lcom/google/ads/g$a;

move-result-object v2

invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Lcom/google/ads/internal/g;->a(Lcom/google/ads/g$a;)V

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->c()Z

move-result v1

if-eqz v1, :cond_2

invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->d()Z

move-result v1

if-eqz v1, :cond_2

iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/google/ads/e;->a:Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;

invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;->h()Lcom/google/ads/m;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/google/ads/m;->b()Z

move-result v1

if-eqz v1, :cond_1

const/4 v1, 0x0

:goto_1
iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/google/ads/e;->a:Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;

new-instance v3, Lcom/google/ads/e$8;

invoke-direct {v3, p0, v0, v1, p4}, Lcom/google/ads/e$8;-><init>(Lcom/google/ads/e;Lcom/google/ads/h;Landroid/view/View;Lcom/google/ads/f;)V

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Lcom/google/ads/internal/d;->a(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V

const/4 v1, 0x1

monitor-exit v0

move v0, v1

:goto_2

# This point!!!

return v0

:cond_1
invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->f()Landroid/view/View;

move-result-object v1

goto :goto_1

:cond_2
invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/ads/h;->b()V

const/4 v1, 0x0

monitor-exit v0
:try_end_2
.catchall {:try_start_2 .. :try_end_2} :catchall_0

move v0, v1

goto :goto_2

:catchall_0
move-exception v1

monitor-exit v0

throw v1
.end method
```

Comment: what is your final intent ?